# $12^7+8^8$ divided by $13$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I Need to find what the remainder is when $12^7+8^8$ is divided by $13$

I have a solution, but don't know if it is right. 
$12=-1\mod13$

$12^7=-1\mod13$

$8=8\mod13$

$8^2=6\mod13$

$8^4=10\mod13$

$8^8=9\mod13$

Then I did $-1\mod13+9\mod13=8\mod13$, so the remainder is $8$.
If someone could tell me if this is correct, it would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! $8^2=-1$ (not $6$) modulo $13$ (See the answers below)

Comment: We have  $8^2\equiv -1$, so $8^4\equiv 1$, so $8^8\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 2):

You are quite incorrect in your calculations. $8^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {13}$ in your second line.

However, there is an easier way you can proceed. $$12^{7}+8^8 \equiv (-1)^7+2^{24} \equiv -1+(2^{12})^2 \equiv -1+1 \pmod {13}$$ since $2^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$ from Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's Little Theorem we have $2^{12}=1\bmod13$. So $8^4=1\bmod13$ and hence $8^8=1\bmod13$. As you said, $12^7=(-1)^7=-1\bmod13$, so $12^7+8^8=0\bmod13$.